# Haystack quates the multiword query instead how to pass unquated query?

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

My solr query is q=xyz OR abc. I am entering this in haystack form.
haystack quotes the query q="xyz OR abc" so OR does not work, so how to achieve this behavior via haystack. In haystack form I should be able to do "q=xyz OR abc AND jkl"

Answer (score 1):

Example from [the docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchquery_api.html#sq-objects):

```
from haystack.query import SQ

# We want "title: Foo AND (tags:bar OR tags:moof)"
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(title='Foo').filter(SQ(tags='bar') | SQ(tags='moof'))
```

Comment: in the form i will enter any combination of AND and OR and it should work transparently

Comment: Never used built-in haystack forms. Looked in the code and found that SearchForm just uses SearchQuerySet.auto_query method (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/query.py#L414). AFAIK, it only parses quotes and excludes. Why do you think AND, OR should work?